# PJSIP Openembedded

Tags: cross-compiling, yocto, openembedded

I want to cross compile PJSIP for my Colibri iMX7 from Toradex. I added my pjsip meta-layer and I wrote the .bb file (http://pastebin.com/y3GTH21w) naming it pjproject_2.6.bb which is the latest version and I changed the checksums.

The tree of my meta-pjproject is as follows:

```
 meta-pjproject
 ├── conf
 │   └── layer.conf
 └── recipes-pjproject
     └── pjproject
         └── pjproject_2.6.bb
         └── MD5SUM.TXT
```

But when compiling it doing `bitbake pjproject` I have this error:

```
 ERROR: configure failed
  ../pjproject-2.6/configure: 2: ../pjproject-2.6/configure: ./aconfigure: not found
```

Here is the log I got : http://pastebin.com/8XAZbAp3

And the folder `/home/boby/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/pjproject/2.6-r0/pjproject-2.6` is empty.

**EDIT:**
Here is a working bb file compiling PJSIP for Openembedded:
pastebin.com/CWQJ1Z8r

Tree of the layer:

```
 meta-pjproject
 ├── conf
 │   └── layer.conf
 └── recipes-pjproject
     └── pjproject
         └── pjproject_2.6.bb
```

But I have a problem, if I do:

```
root@colibri-imx7:# python
>>> import pjsua
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pjsua
```

I seems it is not installing the python lib of PJSIP I tried a lot of things but I could not install it..

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

```
configure: ./aconfigure: not found
```

The configure script is broken and does not work when run from outside the source tree. You can inherit "autotools-brokensep" instead of "autotools" to make bitbake build inside the source tree, or you could fix the project to work with out-of-tree-compilation.

Don't get tempted to write your own do_configure(): autotools and autotools-brokensep classes do a lot of work for you that you really want done.

Also some comments:

```
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://MD5SUM.TXT;md5=xxx"
```

This is almost certainly wrong. You're supposed to refer to a file inside the source tarball. Try "file://COPYING;md5=xxx"

```
EXTRA_OECONF += "STAGING_DIR=${STAGING_DIR_NATIVE}"
```

This looks pretty weird, as do some of the exports in do_compile_append...

Comment: Thank you for your time ! Someone helped me finding the good bb file !

Answer (score 0):

How are you sure this is the good BB file? Because it seems some files are missing on the target image...
Also, assuming you are cross compiling, shouldn't you append

```
EXTRA_OECONF += "--host=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
```

to your recipe?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think since it is in yocto I don't have to add this. And if I try to launch the compiled samples they work just fine. I just have problems installing the python lib.